# Get the count of all the statuses using JPA + spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

The SQL query is working perfectly fine which is

`SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) status_1 , count(CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 END) status_2 , count(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed' THEN 1 END) status_3 FROM lead_details;`

[image]

But when i'm writing similar query in terms of JPA, i'm getting the wrong result

```
@Query(value="SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) status_1\r\n" + 
        "     , count(CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 END) status_2\r\n" + 
        "     , count(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed' THEN 1 END) status_3\r\n" + 
        "  FROM lead_details", nativeQuery=true)
List<Integer> getAllStatusCount();
```

RESULT:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
        count(CASE 
            WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 
        END) status_1       ,
        count(CASE 
            WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 
        END) status_2       ,
        count(CASE 
            WHEN status = 'Closed' THEN 1 
        END) status_3    
    FROM
        lead_details
[5]
```

Comment: Typo in original SQL query? You don't have count before status_1. Maybe that's why you're getting different results.

Comment: Edited...sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the return type - List of Integers. Your query returns one row with three columns, but your return type assumes you'll return multiple rows with one column.

So

1. Either introduce custom type that will be returned (<s>some DTO with three fields</s> [Spring Data Projection Interfaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections))

```
public interface MyCustomDTO {
    Long getStatus1();
    Long getStatus2();
    Long getStatus3();
}
...
@Query(value="SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) status1 ," + 
        "     count(CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 END) status2 , " + 
        "     count(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed' THEN 1 END) status3 " + 
        "     FROM lead_details", nativeQuery=true)
MyCustomDTO getAllStatusCount();
```

2. Or rewrite your query to return three rows with one column using `UNION` (I didn't test, but something like):

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) status FROM lead_details
UNION
SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 END) status FROM lead_details
UNION
SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed' THEN 1 END) status FROM lead_details
```

Comment: Tried with DTO thing but its giving ConverterNotFoundException!!

Comment: Edited my original answer - any DTO will not suffice (got the similar error as you), did some research and found [Spring Data Projection Interfaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) which worked for me.

Comment: Pistolnikus Both the approaches are working fine it solved the issue...